# $\sum\frac {a_n}{(1+a_1).... (1+a_n)}=1$ iff $\sum a_n $ diverges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show if $a_n $ are positive, then
$\sum\frac {a_n}{(1+a_1).... (1+a_n)}=1$ iff  $\sum a_n $ diverges.
I got right to lest side, by bounding by n from below so I got the later series divegres, but could not get the other side. I would love to see an idea please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.**

You have for $n \ge 1$: $$ u_n=\frac{a_n}{(1+a_1) \cdots (1+a_n)}=\frac{1+a_n}{(1+a_1) \cdots (1+a_n)}-\frac{1}{(1+a_1) \cdots (1+a_n)}=v_{n-1}-v_n$$ where $$v_n=\frac{1}{(1+a_1) \cdots (1+a_n)}.$$ Hence $$\sum_{k=1}^n u_n = 1 - v_n.$$ Therefore, $$\sum \frac{a_n}{(1+a_1) \cdots (1+a_n)} = 1$$ if and only if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1+a_1) \cdots (1+a_n) = \infty$.